# wrap function in javascript highcharts

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, highcharts

How do you wrap a function ?

i have asked this before, but am trying to make this question as simple as possible.

So this is the code I need to wrap :

```
$(function () { 
$('#container').highcharts({
chart: {
    type: 'bar'
},
title: {
    text: 'Fruit Consumption'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
},
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Fruit eaten'
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [1, 0, 4]
}, {
    name: 'John',
     data: [5, 7, 3]
 }]
 });
 });​
```

div:

```
<div id="container" style="width:340px; height:270px;"></div>
```

I was told I can put this into a wrap and then call the function. How can this be done?

This data is dummy, my data is coming from the server. What i want is to redraw the chart in code behind so it refreshes the data, using RegisterClientScriptBlock.

but for this, i first need to wrap the function...

i have this, but get error:

```
    Dim someScript As String = "<script language='javascript'>container1_highcharts();</script>"
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "onload", someScript)
```

error:

```
  Uncaught ReferenceError: container_highcharts is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what you need:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
 string someScript = "<script language='javascript'>container_highcharts();</script>";
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "onload", someScript);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var container1_highcharts = function() {
    this.chart = new HighCharts.Chart(options);
}
// then call
var chart = new container1_highcharts();
```

see some jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kreeg/gPAJa/